# Bryce "Zoom to Selection" Function in Blender?

Tags: interface, 3d-view, camera

As a newcomer to Blender, I'm trying to reproduce a few workflow scenarios I once used in Bryce, but now in Blender I can't figure out how to do one simple task that was the backbone of much of my output:

In Bryce I could render a scene, then using a bounding box to select an area, render the selection and see a newly rendered scene that would then fill the 3d view (called "Zoom to Selection" in Bryce). I could then select another  area in that "new" scene, render that selection, and so on, and so on (re-iteratively) quite a ways. Essentially you are slowly zooming in. Each new render was detailed enough to see what I wanted to zoom into further.

The closest I've found in Blender is the "Render Border" function.  Unfortunately, the rendered selection is too undetailed to see well enough to effectively zoom a second time, much less allow for successive iterations. Also, "rendered border" only fills the selected area within the "camera" view. If the selected area is near a border of the main view, then zooming the view to see greater detail in the selection results in part of the image scrolling outside any possible view.

At any rate, if anyone here has worked with the "Zoom to Selection" feature in Bryce, and has a suggestion as to how to recreate it in Blender, I would be overjoyed!

Comment: Maybe a combination of Shift B and Ctrl B outside of camera view?

Comment: Gandalf: Shift B and/or Ctrl B are used to perform the "Render Border" function that I have mentioned as being inadequate for my needs.

Comment: I can't really follow the description, Blender has border-render, and border-zoom.. this seems some combination of both?

Comment: @RobertHamilton You said 'Render Border' wasn't adequate when using *camera view*, but didn't say why using render border *outside* of camera view isn't suitable. Are you using the live render view (which sounds like what you need) or are you doing a full render?

Comment: @RobertHamilton Shift B *outside of camera view* acts as a zoom border. Are you rendering with F12 (full render) or in the viewport?

Comment: Ray and Gandalf: I wasn't rendering outside the camera because I wanted a smaller area that happened to be within the camera view. I then did a live render followed by a full render.

Answer (score 2):

- If the idea is to move your camera towards the rectangle selection,
  you can lock the camera to view (in "N" panel) and use Shift+B
- if you want to really "Zoom" perfectly in your rectangle, you can use this addon I made : https://caetano-veyssieres.com/blender/, using the "Crop" button and multiplying the resolution to your needs. You can't re-iterate the process at the moment but I hope to make it possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just rephrasing answers already given, but, if I understand what you want to do:

1. Render your scene
2. Use Ctrl-B in the rendered view to define the area you want to zoom/enhance (i.e., set the render border)
3. Increase the render resolution, e.g. double it
4. Hit F12, the area within your render border will be re-rendered at the higher resolution
5. Zoom in to see your newly rendered area better, Shift-B may help here, you may need to hit Home first to see where the rendered area has gone

Repeat as desired, use Ctrl-Alt-B to reset render border when you're done.

I think the "increase the render resolution" is the bit you've been missing. 
 Unlike the Bryce feature you're describing, looks like this has to be done manually in Blender.